# Dict comprehension in Python not PEP8

Tags: python, pep8

My Sublime Linter for `Python 2.7` reports that this line is not PEP8:

```
D = {k:get_distance(v) for k, v in D.items() if len(v) > 1}
```

in column `8` and `27`

but when I insert a space after colon (`:`), I get a red exclamation mark in Sublime.

[image: sublime scr]

How to make this line `PEP8` compliant?

**Update**

Sublime Text 2.0.2, build 2221 ;
Sublime Linter v1.8 ;
Python PEP8 Lint v2013.10.11.06

Code works and produces output without error

Comment: Adding a space shouldn't give a syntax error. The error was probably caused by something else.

Comment: Inserting a space after the colon is not a syntax error. Please show the full error message you get.

Comment: Interesting. Code works, but Sublime reports an error sign (red exclamation mark).

Comment: @oski86: so what version of the linter are you using? What configuration? Have you tried running the code?

Comment: @oski86: I can't reproduce this with SublimeLinter 3.5, standard configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a space after the `:`; this is still valid Python syntax:

```
D = {k: get_distance(v) for k, v in D.items() if len(v) > 1}
```

If you are getting a syntax error, you introduced that somewhere else. Perhaps you forgot to close a `)` parenthesis on the preceding line, for example.

Note that using a capital letter as a local variable is not PEP-8 compliant. Pick better, lowercase_with_underscores names for local variables:

```
def solution(seq):
    positions = defaultdict(list)
    for i, item in enumerate(seq):
        positions[item].append(i)
    distances = {k: get_distance(v) for k, v in positions.items() if len(v) > 1}
    return max(distances.value()) if distances else 0
```

Last but not least; your indices in the `positions` dictionary are *ordered* (incrementing), so `get_distance()` should just return `l[-1] - l[0]` to make it return a distance in O(1) constant time.

Comment: This answers my question fully. Seems like I have an outdated Sublime environment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
D = {k: get_distance(v) for k, v in D.items() if len(v) > 1}
```

This is not a syntactical error and is the correct PEP8 way to write it. Check that you do not have any hidden unicode character in there.